# SQL Query not working, php?

Tags: php, mysql

i am using the mysql, the error i think is on the mysql_query because the return false on if condition, this is the code and i cant find the error, the "time" is data-time information
sscript

```
    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ;

$strsqld = "SELECT 'time' FROM 'tssa_banner_central' WHERE  'time' >  '$now'";


    if($result=mysql_query($db,$strsqld)){echo("ahre");};


    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo ($row["time"]);
        };


    }
```

other script (the require is included)

```
function connect() {
        $db = mysql_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
        if (!$db || !mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $db)) {
            die('***');
            }       
        return $db;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: what u mean? the msqli was a error on the paste, fixed

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York").` ? Why the period? You need a semicolon there.

Comment: @user10039997 Well, you should be using mysqli (or PDO), mysql_* functions are removed in PHP7 and frowned upon.  Either way, you aren't checking the value of $result or doing any error handling.

Comment: See the manual page for [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query). The first parameter is the SQL string, and the second is the link identifier. You have them the wrong way around. Also, notice the big red warning notice on that page. You shouldn't be using mysql_* functions anymore. Instead use PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

replace all mysql with mysqli and mysqli_select_db ( $db , DB_NAME)
example:
mysql_fetch_assoc with mysqli_fetch_assoc
mysql_fetch_array with mysqli_fetch_array